# Share an image from my server on other websites in ASP.net, like photo hosting services

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image

i'm sending an email with a HTML format using C# in an ASP.net web-app, this mail contains images located on my server, its source embedded into HTML.

how can it be shown in the email or on another web pages through HTML code or any other technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for many days ... i added a shared SSL folder (which can be accessed publicly) to my website and uploaded the image in it then i embedded its link in the email body like:

```
<img src="http://frostyserver.com/pub/Logo.png" width="150" height="150" style="float: left">
```